# Videos play without sound

Tags: video, sound, 9.10

When I play any video on Ubuntu 9.10, volume is not there. Is it lacking a package?

Comment: why dont you use the latest version 10.10? I think that would be the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have sound when playing a video, here's some general advice:

- Assume the simplest cause and work from there.
- Does it depend on that video? Can you play a simple sound file (like one from [this page](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/wav/wav.html)) If the WAV file plays fine, it might be related to a missing audio codec, or to your media player application.
- Is the volume up - both PCM and Master volume, if that applies to your case - and the sound not muted? You can check that by right-clicking on the volume meter in your systray.
- Is your stereo properly connected and set up, no headphones plugged in?
- Does sound work on another operating system?

If these do not point to a cause of the problem, it might very well be a driver problem. In that case you should:

- Find out if your sound card was detected at all;
- Use a more full-featured mixer program, such as `alsamixer`, and see if changing the settings has any effect;
- Find out your audio chipset. This can be done by running `lspci` in the terminal and watching out for what loooks like a sound card;
- Google that sound card, or the driver used for it. In some cases, adding a module option can bring the sound card to life.

If it is indeed a driver issue, it might help to check if the card works under Ubuntu 10.10 - you can verify this easily by using live media such as a CD or a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the alsa-* package installed ?

Try with:

`dpkg -l |grep alsa`

Answer (score 0):

if you cant upgrade to 10.10, try these:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras package

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-pitfdll gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libxine1-ffmpeg
```

Comment: ubc@ubc-desktop:~$ dpkg -l |grep alsasudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras package
grep: apt-get: No such file or directory
grep: install: No such file or directory
grep: ubuntu-restricted-extras: No such file or directory
grep: package: No such file or directory
ubc@ubc-desktop:~$ 
its give some error when i use the given command

Comment: @shalu: there is a small mistake in your command. dpkg -l |grep alsa  and sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras are two different commands and need to execute one by one.

just run the above three commands one by one. you will be fine

Comment: ubc@ubc-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras package
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version.
E: Couldn't find package package

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems with sound, click the Volume applet, then Sound Preferences, and check your Volume, Hardware, Input, and Output settings.  If that fails, see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sound

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

http://alsa.opensrc.org/DmixPlugin

Comment: The developers recommend https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio as a starting point.